# How to use std::shared_ptr as class member?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, smart-pointers

I need to create a class like this. But when I run this code, I get:

```
"Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (fast)"
```

What's wrong with MyClass? How to use shared_ptr as a class member correctly?

```
#include <memory>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(unsigned size) {
        _size = size;
        _arr = std::make_shared<int>(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            _arr.get()[i] = 0;
    }

    MyClass(const MyClass& other) {
        _arr = other._arr;
        _size = other._size;
    }

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other) {
        _arr = other._arr;
        _size = other._size;
    }

    void setArr(std::shared_ptr<int> arr, unsigned size) {
        _size = size;
        _arr = arr;
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        _arr.reset();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<int> _arr;
    unsigned _size;
};

int main() {
    MyClass m(4);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you, I misunderstood what make_shared makes. If I want to use int* (not std::vector or std::array), should I write this? (and don't fix the other methods)

```
    MyClass(unsigned size) {
        _size = size;
        _arr = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int[size]);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            _arr.get()[i] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Hint: pointers are not arrays. Think carefully about what this means: `std::make_shared<int>(size);`.

Comment: Also note that your issue has nothing to do with the smart pointer being a data member.

Comment: You say you "need to create a class like this" and that you don't "want to use" the easy standard solution (`std::vector`). Why? What is the reason that you absolutely must use `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I need few MyClass objects, and some of them have the same _arr.

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov: Have you considered `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl I don't need dynamic array, but probably I should use C++11 std::array

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov: Yes, do you do need a "dynamic array" (i.e. a `std::vector` in real code, unless you have a **very** special use case that demands manual use of placement new) if the size is only known at run-time.You can use `std::array` only if you know the size before the program runs. Just don't use `new[]`, ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, look how [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) works.

Basically, *std::make_shared*

> Constructs an object of type T and wraps it in a std::shared_ptr

In your case *T* is *int*, so *std::make_shared* created an object of type *int* and wraps it in a *std::shared_ptr*. As a result memory is allocated for a single *int*, not for an array of *int*s and your program causes *Undefined Behaviour*.

I suppose you can use [std::default_delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete) to avoid problems:

```
_arr = std::shared_ptr<int>(new int[size], std::default_delete<int[]>());
```

Also note, that:

1. Your *operator=* returns nothing.
2. You shouldn't start variables names with an underscore.
3. It's not necessary to call *reset()* for *_arr* in the class destructor.

Comment: `std::vector` won't have the same ownership semantics. That may actually be a good thing, but not what OP is aiming for.

Comment: Thank you! What about setArr() method, is it right? Should I  pass std::shared_ptr<int>& instead of std::shared_ptr<int>?

Comment: You should pass *std::shared_ptr* by value because it is a pointer abstraction. Also use *std::shared_ptr* with the appropriate deleter.

Comment: If I pass by value, counter of shared_ptr will increase. But If I pass by reference, counter will not increase. Am I right?

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov The `setArr` method is broken because you can pass a size that doesn't match the "size" or the shared_prt's array. Just remove it, and the assignment operator, copy constructor and destructor, and use the ones the compiler makes for you.

Comment: @juanchopanza I am not going to pass wrong size to the method :) But I want to use code like this `MyClass x(10); MyClass y(10); ...; y.setArr(x.getArr(), x.getSize());`

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov: If the number 10 is known beforehand, then you can use `std::shared_ptr<std::array<int, N>>` and make `MyClass` a template. Note that your real question already deviates *a lot* from your original question (how to use `std::shared_ptr` as a class member).

Comment: @AnatoliySultanov All you need it `y = x;`

Comment: @juanchopanza MyClass has other field too (_name), not only _arr and _size, and I don't want replace y._name by x._name. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/148827/using-shared-ptr-as-class-member

Comment: It is somewhat easier to avoid underscore at the beginning of a name that to remember the exact rules (global or local scope, 1 or 2 leading _ and also upper or lower case initial letter...).